# Can not get custom sql by id in liferay

Tags: postgresql, liferay, postgresql-9.1, liferay-service-builder

I try to use custom sql of service buider, but I can't get custom query from file default.xml. I tried to debug but it return null at sql of  Student1FinderImpl . Can anyone help me?
Here is my code:
 default.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<custom-sql>
       <sql id="searchByNameStudent1">
              <![CDATA[
                     SELECT * FROM database_student1 WHERE name= ?
              ]]>
       </sql>
    </custom-sql>






 public class Student1FinderImpl extends BasePersistenceImpl<Student1> implements Student1Finder  {
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Student1> searchByName(String name,int start,int end){
     Session session= null;
     String sql= "";
     try{
            //open session
            session= openSession();
            //set SQL by ID
            sql=CustomSQLUtil.get("searchByNameStudent1");
            SQLQuery query= session.createSQLQuery(sql);
            query.addEntity("Student1", Student1.class);
            query.setCacheable(false);
            QueryPos qPos= QueryPos.getInstance(query);
            qPos.add(name);
            System.out.println(query);
            return (List<Student1>) QueryUtil.list(query, getDialect(), start, end);
     }
     catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
     }
     finally{
            closeSession(session);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the name you declared for sql query is correct, I have always used the developer guide specification in my work, since you are missing the sql at all the name convention may be the cause,you should try their way since your developing Liferay applications

```
<custom-sql>
    <sql id="com.myproject.portlet.service.persistence.Student1FinderImpl.searchByName"">
    <![CDATA[
                 SELECT * FROM database_student1 WHERE name= ?
          ]]>
    </sql>
</custom-sql>
```

Also make sure the directory of `default.xml` is `docroot/WEB-INF/src/custom-sql/`

see:  [Liferay:DEVELOPING CUSTOM SQL QUERIES](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/developing-custom-sql-queries)